# Events not firing in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a textfield with drop down suggestion box. I created a plugin for the textfield to display search suggestions. But the keyup and blur events are not firing.

```
    (function($){
    $.fn.suggestions = function(input, suggestbox, options){
        alert("page loaded");
        alert(this.css("visibility"));
        this.keyup(function(event){
                alert(this.val());
                if(this.val() != ""){
                    $(suggestbox).css("visibility", "visible");
                    alert($(suggestbox).css("visibility"));
                    $(suggestbox).hide();
                    $(suggestbox).fadeIn("fast");
                    var query = this.val();
                    $(suggestbox).empty();
                    $(suggestbox).append("<ul>").css({
                                'list-style-type': 'none',
                                'cursor': 'pointer'
                            });
                    input(query, function(companies){
                        $.each(companies, function(index, value){
                            $(suggestbox).append("<li>" + value + "</li>").children("li").mouseover(function(event){
                                $(this).removeClass(options.mouseoutcss);
                                $(this).addClass(options.mouseincss);
                            }).mouseout(function(){
                                $(this).removeClass(options.mouseincss);
                                $(this).addClass(options.mouseoutcss);
                            }).click(function(){
                                        this.val($(this).text());
                                        $(suggestbox).hide();
                                    });
                        });
                    });
                    $(suggestbox).append("</ul>");
                }else{
                    $(suggestbox).fadeOut("fast", function(){
                        $(suggestbox).css("visibility", "hidden");
                    });
                }
            });

            this.blur(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    if($(suggestbox).css("visibility") == "visible"){
                        $(suggestbox).hide();
                    }
                }, 200);
            });

    };

}) (jQuery);
```

I've also tried the following but no luck either.

```
        this.each(function(){
    $(this).keyup(function(event){....});
});
```

Comment: have a look in your javascript console, are there any errors there?

Comment: yes, it stucks at this.val(), which I thought `this` is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Cause

`this.val` is not a function in your keyup handler. `this` would refer to the html element, not a jQuery object. Your handler is being triggered, but it is throwing an error right at the start.

#### Solution

Ensure that you are using a jQuery object where appropriate in your handlers. For example, change `this.val` to `$(this).val`. I have created [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WABCB/) demonstrating some of the required fixes. It will not completely work, as the code you gave was incomplete, but it should show you some of the corrections that are required.

#### Notes

- `this`, in the scope of the jQuery plugin, is a jQuery object.
- `this`, in the scope of an event handler, is an HTML element object.
- To get a jQuery object for a given HTML element object, do `$(myHtmlElem)`, where `myHtmlElem` is an HTML element object.

Comment: dude, you are f***ing awesome! works like charm and thanks for the extra effort to put it in jsFiddle!!

Answer (score 0):

`alert(this.val())` is an error (`this` is a DOM element inside the event handler), which breaks the execution of the event handler.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are correct as well, but I followed Spycho's answer and got it right. Thanks again!! :O)